# Multiple "could not be resolved" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, simulink

I'm trying to compile simulink generated code using Eclipse. I'm using several header files from simulink's library. In particular, `rtwsolver.h` is giving several 'could not be resolved' errors, to some standard C data types, which is strange also because I have another file in the project which uses some of the same data types and it compiles without an issue.

The errors I'm getting:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 48 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 49 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 88 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 89 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 90 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 91 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 95 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 96 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 97 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 98 Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 112    Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 113    Semantic Error
Type 'boolean_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 117    Semantic Error
Type 'char_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 47 Semantic Error
Type 'char_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 106    Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 58 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 59 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 60 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 61 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 63 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 65 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 66 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 68 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 75 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 78 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 79 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 85 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 93 Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 101    Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 102    Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 103    Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 110    Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 111    Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 115    Semantic Error
Type 'int_T' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 116    Semantic Error
Type 'real_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 62 Semantic Error
Type 'real_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 69 Semantic Error
Type 'real_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 70 Semantic Error
Type 'real_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 72 Semantic Error
Type 'real_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 76 Semantic Error
Type 'real_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 80 Semantic Error
Type 'real_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 82 Semantic Error
Type 'real_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 104    Semantic Error
Type 'real_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 109    Semantic Error
Type 'RTWRTModelMethodsInfo' could not be resolved  rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 108    Semantic Error
Type 'SimTimeStep' could not be resolved    rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 45 Semantic Error
Type 'SolverMode' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 50 Semantic Error
Type 'ssMatrixType' could not be resolved   rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 100    Semantic Error
Type 'time_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 52 Semantic Error
Type 'time_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 53 Semantic Error
Type 'time_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 54 Semantic Error
Type 'time_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 55 Semantic Error
Type 'time_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 56 Semantic Error
Type 'time_T' could not be resolved rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 73 Semantic Error
Type 'uint8_T' could not be resolved    rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 83 Semantic Error
Type 'uint8_T' could not be resolved    rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 84 Semantic Error
Type 'uint8_T' could not be resolved    rtw_solver.h    /CAN1/include/simulink/include  line 86 Semantic Error
```

Answer (score 0):

Closed the project, re-opened it and voila, the errors went away. God bless Eclipse.